# Excel 2007 formula to extract 90-90 character sentences from a paragraph

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2007

Posting this question again as I could still not find the proper solution.

Paragraph in cell A1:

```
Buy a Arlen Ness Big Sucker Stage 1 Air Kit with Beveled Cover for 17-Up HD Touring Softail and get FREE SHIPPING from our website xyz.com. Order today.
```

Expected value in B1:

```
Buy a Arlen Ness Big Sucker Stage 1 Air Kit with Beveled Cover for 17-Up HD Touring
```

Expected value in C1: Softail and get FREE SHIPPING from our website xyz.com. Order today.

What formula should I use in cell B1 and C1 to exactly pull those two 90-90 character sentences without breaking the end word in parts?

I attempted

```
=LEFT(A1,90)
```

But it is giving the value where the last word is breaking i.e.

```
Buy a Arlen Ness Big Sucker Stage 1 Air Kit with Beveled Cover for 17-Up HD Touring Softai
```

I exactly need formula to give me a complete sentence without seeing end word breaking even if it is less than 90 character.

Comment: In cell `B1` you can use the  [array formula](https://exceljet.net/glossary/array-formula) `=LEFT(A1,MAX((COLUMN(A1:CM1))*(MID(A1,COLUMN(A1:CM1),1)=" ")))`, and in cell `C1` you can use the regular formula `=REPLACE(A1,1,LEN(B1),"")`

Answer (score 0):

In `B1` you could use:
`=LEFT(A1,MAX(IFERROR(FIND(" ",LEFT(A1,91),ROW(1:91)),0))-1)`

I think it requires entering with `ctrl+shift+enter`

It first takes the left 91st characters and checks the position of the last found space character (max number).
Then it returns the left of `A1` to that position minus one (exclude the space character itself)

For `C1` (and dragged down) you could use:
`=LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A$1&" ",TEXTJOIN(" ",1,A$2:A2)&" ",""),MAX(IFERROR(FIND(" ",LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A$1&" ",TEXTJOIN(" ",1,A$2:A2)&" ",""),91),ROW($1:$91)),0))-1)`